# Is there a standard way to subscribe to a feed using a podcast app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mime-types, podcast

Normally, when a podcast is displayed in the browser it does not offer to open with a podcast manager. I looked in the [Swallowcatcher manifest](http://gitorious.org/swallowcatcher/swallowcatcher/blobs/master/AndroidManifest.xml), it will handle feed://url and podcast://url and itpc:// intents to subscribe to podcasts, though it seems to be the *only* app that lets you do this.

Unfortunately, it appears Swallowcatcher is [being discontinued](https://f-droid.org/forums/topic/swallowcatcher/), and has been removed from the app-store. :(

Is this the best way to call a podcast manager? Is "feed" or "podcast" the standard android scheme to call whatever podcast manager the user has installed (doggcatcher/swallowcatcher/Google listen/beyondpod/etc.), or is there a more standard way to call an Android podcast app?

*Update*

Looking at [this](https://github.com/danieloeh/AntennaPod/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml), you would think that you could subscribe using:

```
        Intent bymime = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        bymime.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        bymime.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        bymime.setType("application/xml");
        _context.startActivity(bymime);
```

...but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

**Update**

Stepping into the setData and setType functions (with Android source installed and the sdk/sources folder added) I found that setType sets data null, and setData sets type null.

The solution that works is:

```
        Intent bymime = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        bymime.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        bymime.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/xml");
        _context.startActivity(bymime);
```

This works in Antennapod... but now the question is, how many other podcast apps will catch this? Is this the standard way to subscribe to a podcast with another app?

Answer (score 4):

Typically a podcast is an RSS feed, here are the spec's from apple (who get credit for coining the term obviously, so they're specs are relevant) :

http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#example

Other than those two protocol scheme, you may also consider "`itpc://`" - An itunes podcast link  (and hey, would be cool on android and there's a ton of podcast out there with it)   =D

Comment: I think you mean itpc://url ? I know that shortcut works for iTunes and other programs on a desktop computer, but not for Android, at least not Swallowcatcher. I want to know how to use an *intent* to subscribe to a podcast url.

Comment: Right, I totally get that, I'm saying to add that add that sucker in there - there isn't any reason you can't latch the itpc just like *feed* and *podcast*  ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand, you mean change Swallowcatcher and recompile it? I'm just looking for a way to call any installed podcast app and subscribe to a certain url of a podcast. Can you provide example Java code? - thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you wanted to build a podcast catcher. I misread your question. :S

Comment: Calling an intent with itpc:// url seems to be the best way, Swallowcatcher will now work with those links, and other podcast managers for Android would probably catch itpc urls also.

Comment: Unfortunately itpc:// is no longer supported on any recent versions of Mac or Linux/PC it appears.

Answer (score 2):

Just got Google Listen to work by changing
itpc:/url
to 
feed:/url

Comment: Unfortunately I've seen few itpc:// urls, but fewer feed:// urls. Good to know those work in that podcatcher though, I wonder why it doesn't handle itpc?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find any good way of linking using url schemes. However this "catcher" seems to work for most current podcast apps:
https://subscribeonandroid.com/

Simply modify the url to include your feed:

```
https://subscribeonandroid.com/yoururl.com/yourfeed.rss
```

Answer (score 0):

The iTunes-specific command solution would be,

```
iTunes /url "pcast:https://(link_to_rss)"
```

OR

```
iTunes /url "itpc://(link_to_rss)"
```

The two commands work differently, with no apparent way to tell which one to use.