# How do I structure an Intent to open a Podcast App using an RSS Feed URL?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that has dynamic podcast / RSS feed URLs generated by users. For example, let's use this url:

```
http://leccap.engin.umich.edu/leccap/feed/podcast/sample-rec-7d9gq34m/4
```

As these URLs are generated on the fly by content creators I need to take the URL that is passed to me by the API and create an intent that opens up a podcast app. While I am not endorsing any of these, in order to provide context, here are some podcast app examples for anyone unfamiliar:

- [Google Podcasts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.podcasts&hl=en_US&gl=US)
- [Pocket Casts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts&hl=en_US&gl=US)
- [Podcast Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.podcast.podcasts&hl=en_US&gl=US)

As the intent I am sending could be opened by any / all of these apps, I don't need to support a singular one as much as just figure out the correct Intent builder logic so that the user can choose which one they want to use.

I have this base code setup:

```java
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        //Setting data / categories here

        this.startActivity(intent);
```

And I have tried the following variations on the intent categories & data:

```java
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(podcastUrl), "*/*");
```

```java
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(podcastUrl), "application/xml");
```

```java
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(podcastUrl));
```

```java
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(podcastUrl));
```

```java
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(podcastUrl));
        intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Selection");
```

none of which work to actually redirect into a native podcast player app via deep linking. I have also tried multiple variations on the `category` option and none of them seem to improve things.

As per [Is there a standard way to subscribe to a feed using a podcast app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797461/is-there-a-standard-way-to-subscribe-to-a-feed-using-a-podcast-app) I have also tried replacing the `http:` / `https:` string with `feed` and `itpc`, IE

```
feed://leccap.engin.umich.edu/leccap/feed/podcast/sample-rec-7d9gq34m/4
```

And still nothing.

**How do I go about structuring this Intent so that it will present the user options to open a Podcast app to handle said feed URL?**

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly ... what you are saying is once I click the `leccap.engin.umich.edu/leccap/feed/podcast/sample-rec-7d9gq34m/4` app should take me to any of those listed apps right ?

Comment: Correct, using that sample link as a url, I would like the user to be presented with a list of options they can choose to open the URL. From my research, it looks like I can pick certain deep-linking schemas like Google Podcasts app or Spotify, but I cannot find a way to do it for any apps that can play podcasts.

Comment: Have you came accross any other apps that have this feature i.e clicking on the same link you provided?

Comment: @AgentP a few misc ones in passing, but I have only ever seen Google Podcasts open on my device; moreover if you don't have Google Podcasts installed it won't redirect into that for the specific app I was testing.

Comment: Any updates? Searching for the same answer

Comment: I never found an effective way to do it in `general`. I ended up using this url as the base `https://www.google.com/podcasts?` and then appended an `auth_token={x}` generated by our server to get it to work. It works with Google podcasts, but that's about it :/